# C4913 warning triggered by throwing an exception

Tags: c++, visual-c++, warnings

I have some code like this:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

namespace some_space {
    struct some_class{
    };

    some_class operator,(some_class a, float ){
        return a;
    }

    int a(){
        // somewhere in this function
        throw std::exception{};
    }
}
```

Compiled with MSVC and `/W4` I get this warning:

```
<source>(13): warning C4913: user defined binary operator ',' exists but no overload could convert all operands, default built-in binary operator ',' used
```

I am wondering why the line 13 `throw std::exception{};` causes this warning. Has anyone an explanation for this?

The [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4913?view=msvc-160) for this warning only lists an example, where the comma operator is used. However, in the this case, I do not see the use of the operator.

Here is a link to a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BAVU1AnUNBEUR0bEJtvWNzTltwz2hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzKHI3lgA1CYbbgoEWKqrSQSH2CYaAIK3d8xsCklMq3sKqGwA%2Bq/vmAOAHYrPc9uDPgRiF4HJ9vpgfjsmAoFCYQY8IcCACKHUEPMEQr6/JEovaoJKxJhEMgQIkIkkKPZMUh7Ki0VBUvZzNF4zGY4iYAjLBhM3EYiFonH3cXg0IEJkQbnogl8vYAejVcLYAHcELFAaE9gQEHhGVQvAwOgwZXzjcRUNrIegQCBMOdMJcMjzJWKVdjHpKOAtaJx4rw/BwtKRUJw3NZrHDlh9NjxSARNEGFgBrfwATgAdFwzFwAGySMwbIGV%2BJAjRA/ScSThjPRzi8BQgDRpjMLOCwGCIFDfJJ0WLkShoFgj%2BhxABuyCSSR%2Bs64uZ%2BBgImBOP1UZdIWFneFWADU8JhtQB5CkR1M0Wib4gdiBRFtRUINACenFTb%2BYxA/F5RNo1TptwvCTmwggXgwtBfpGvBYCwhjAOI8H7ngAo1LOW4tm61ReJuLZypgIZobQeBRMQn4eFg368FCeAsHRCxskwwAKKe55XowdEyIIIhiOwUh8fIShqC2uhcPoyEoPGlj6BRHaQAs5KOAIHZqgA6tI7RqX4ECuKMfhScEUwlGUegpGkelGZZ%2BR6b05mzLYJEgbUEy2VJunud0jn9OUQzdJ5gWNH5MzlAsXxJkJwahs2aExhwey7pIewsAo857CuBYblu8oQLghAkAcFZcHM9E9tmIAbAWJZAhUuZArmZjxBsxYVA2HBNqQTHxF2EZRol7adt28G9gOEBIIu44QEiRgALT8MQSGgammD4NSeDOlJd4PvNepMFgj4tvw/GiOIwmnaJKjqGhklpgKmBbZ2sUcGGpADbwiXKAKST2qsKLFReBFJARyVlmlGXIFlq75rlJx7AVG3FSmLIeFOo7ECVGxlRVY0LAdR2UK93W9f1LZDbYI2gVocxVTV%2BZ1Q1TUtW1XAdaRGzxYNbajbTpB9lAE1IEsBCgwQM3rUVxDPTtsgCRd0hXYoN0SXo2pUUkzGde9n2thwwNi2DqBUODqXpZl2Vw1SeWI%2Bj06xNjuN85mpA5mYZj5hoGgbBs5ZmE1AAcNWNfWpGkyAfUfRTvMdl2NNBgLwuuqo%2BHUjNDTscohgkUICAOje4HDnQVIZNnYS0HnBctpODtxMARYBLXmPhKwaxFxjM6G1X2p63hyB3MQ7G8/3dT4BGvBXQrQlK7IKviXdegGEYsmWNYClREpirRp66mx0sKxCUM4/l7n%2Be97xGtMFrYGvbrMccNgqfIARxWqIHJbzRDwDINDRb5mYO2ckbB7EKtSJ25UXZ01IITAY29w68DJtHBKsdqaVTdtVLgACNB1XiI1b2zUuBAg/p1LmyCeYcDxrTV6ZhuZfV5gnaB2FHwZBAJIIAA%3D%3D%3D) showing this warning. On idea I had was, that maybe a Macro causes an issue, but the preprocessor output does not show any replacements.

Throwing built in type like `int` or classes convertible to `some_class` do not cause the warning.
Throwing any other classes trigger the warning.

Comment: @Eljay which part doesn't match? I suppose I'm blind.

Comment: @user • isn't relevant for the C4913 warning, so I deleted my comment.  The `operator,(int, float)`.  Seems like a minor bug in the compiler.

Comment: @Eljay where? I don't see "`operator,(int, float`" here or in the godbolt.